# Calculating $\int_0^\infty(\log t)^n e^{-t}\ dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

While messing around trying to calculate a power series for the Gamma function, I ran across this integral:

$$\int_0^\infty(\log t)^n e^{-t}\ dt,\ n \in \mathbb{N}$$

I've looked at it for a while and tried a couple of things, but I'm stumped. Is there a way to calculate this?

Comment: Where do you get it? Try it here http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: Mathematica gives an answer in term of Euler's $\gamma$ and values of the $\zeta$ functions. For example, for $n=5$ the result is  $-20 \gamma ^2 \zeta (3)-\frac{10 \pi
   ^2 \zeta (3)}{3}-24 \zeta
   (5)-\gamma ^5-\frac{5 \gamma ^3 \pi
   ^2}{3}-\frac{3 \gamma  \pi ^4}{4}$.

Comment: Just wondering - does this look to anyone else like the laplace transform of the function $(\log t)^n$ evaluated at $s=1$, or is that irrelevant?

Answer (score 4):

It is the $n$th derivative of the gamma function evaluated at the point $s=1$, where gamma function is given by

$$ \Gamma(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}e^{-x} dx \implies \Gamma^{(n)}(s)|_{s=1}=\int_{0}^{\infty} (\ln(x))^{n}e^{-x} dx .$$

**Added:** You can start from the point

$$ \psi(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\ln \Gamma(x) =\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)} \implies \Gamma'(x)=\Gamma(x)\psi(x),$$

where $\psi(x)$ is the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Comment: Well, yes, that's where I got it from.

Comment: @JavierBadia: Well, you should have mentioned in your post that you knew it is the nth derivative of the gamma function!

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. Expanding $t^{s-1}e^{-t}$ as a power series in $s-1$, you get this integral where the nth derivative goes. But in my question I asked how to calculate it, so this is besides the point.

Comment: @JavierBadia: No problem.

Answer (score 0):

See the pattern?
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \operatorname{ln} (t)^{7} \operatorname{e} ^{-t} d t = -\gamma^{7} - \frac{61 \pi^{6} \gamma}{24} - 84 \zeta (5) \pi^{2} - 
\frac{21 \pi^{4} \zeta (3)}{2} - 280 \zeta (3)^{2} \gamma - 70 \zeta (3) \pi^{2} \gamma^{2} - 
504 \zeta (5) \gamma^{2} - \frac{21 \pi^{4} \gamma^{3}}{4} - 70 \zeta (3) \gamma^{4} - \frac{7 \pi^{2} \gamma^{5}}{2} -  
720 \zeta (7)
$$
(Computed by Maple)

Comment: Actually, sorry, but I don't.